# JOIN query not returning all results

Tags: php, mysql, join

In my admin panel I have access to View/Edit/Delete privileges, and I need to have access to view reviews that users have posted, along with the album name and date. At the moment, I am using a LEFT JOIN, but that only brings up the date and the review, not the album name.

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){

    $get_id = $_GET['id'];

    require_once 'database_conn.php';

    $sql = "SELECT cdreview.reviewText, 
                   cdreview.reviewDate, 
                   cd.CDTitle 
            FROM cdreview 
            LEFT JOIN cd 
              ON cdreview.CDID = cd.CDID 
            WHERE cdreview.userID = '$get_id' 
            ORDER BY reviewDate ASC";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

        $date = $row['reviewDate'];
        $album = $row['CDTitle'];
        $review = $row ['reviewText'];
    }

?>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your query and code look fine to me, at least at first glance.  What values are you getting for the `CDTitle`?

Answer (score 1):

In your db model `CDReview` should have `FK` to `CD` because you can only review existing `CD`, so you should use `INNER JOIN`

The fact you are doing `LEFT JOIN` make me think you can delete `CD`. So my guess is you delete the `CD` for that review.

So check your db model, and if possible show us your `CREATE TABLE` in the question